# Should we make a tag for "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?" What should it be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've noticed we have some questions with the [blade-runner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-runner) *and* with the [phillip-k-dick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phillip-k-dick) tags<sup>1</sup>, which are actually not about *Blade Runner*, but the original novel. I tried to create a [do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep) tag, but predictably ran into the 25-character limit.

These are the questions that are about the novel, or should have the novel tag as well as the film tag (there's probably more, so feel free to add):

- [Who throws the stone at Deckard in "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124880/who-throws-the-stone-at-deckard-in-do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep)
- [In Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?, why is Rosen corp. trying to stop bounty hunters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60011/in-do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep-why-is-rosen-corp-trying-to-stop-bount)
- [In Dick's "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", is Deckard a replicant?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15462/in-dicks-do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep-is-deckard-a-replicant)
- [Can someone explain the end of Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30865/can-someone-explain-the-end-of-do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep)
- [Are the owls in Futurama a backwards reference to Blade Runner and Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18186/are-the-owls-in-futurama-a-backwards-reference-to-blade-runner-and-do-androids-d)
- [Why does Eldon admit that Rachel is an Android after the final question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149191/why-does-eldon-admit-that-rachel-is-an-android-after-the-final-question)
- [Do the androids need to kill their owners in Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120305/do-the-androids-need-to-kill-their-owners-in-do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep)
- [Why was Philip K Dick so distressed at Ridley Scott's adaptation of 'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38864/why-was-philip-k-dick-so-distressed-at-ridley-scotts-adaptation-of-do-androids)
- [Why not test androids by asking them to hold their breath?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60010/why-not-test-androids-by-asking-them-to-hold-their-breath)
- [Why did Deckard get a citation from his police department?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30840/why-did-deckard-get-a-citation-from-his-police-department)

I count 9, which is more than worthy of its own tag. However, the character limit won't allow us to use the full title (and not even [do-androids-dream-electric-sheep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream-electric-sheep) - what should we use instead? [do-androids-dream](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream) seems good to me (until a film or a book titled *Do Androids Dream* comes out).

Any other ideas?

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Note that I somehow foolishly removed the author tag from some 4 of them - we all make mistakes, right ;)</sub>

Comment: `DADES`? We've already got [tag:dada]

Comment: [dadoes]? Seems betters.

Comment: or `androiddreamelectricsheep`

Comment: But the problem is that people will start typing [do-androi...] and won't find it then.

Comment: Make it a synonym of `do-androids-dream-of` i.e. make a bunch of synonyms that might point to it usefully.

Comment: That makes sense. Now put that into an answer :)

Comment: meh. Self-answer?

Comment: @Edlothiad: You mean [tag:correcthorsebatterystaple] ([link](https://xkcd.com/936/))

Comment: @ThePopMachine A relevant xkcd, as always!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to [increase our maximum tag length](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11018/19561) to 35 characters and use [do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep).

**Update:** Tag limit [already increased to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490) and tag also created.

Comment: done now........

Comment: Yep, I saw it. Good job, folks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Until the experiments with tag length over at [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12510/163539) and [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/11) prove successful and we get a length extension as well, I propose we go with [do-androids-dream](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream). I believe it quite unambiguously refers to Dick's novel, and it will show up in suggested tags when starting to type "Do Androids...".

Later, when we get the increase to tag length, we can rename it to [do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep) (which is exactly 35 characters), as SQB suggests.