# Can we please increase our tag length?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

#### Request

Currently, our tags can be a maximum of 25 characters.
Maximum tag length on *Literature* [has been increased to 32 characters](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/13).

The theoretical limit is 35, according to Shog9.

> This can be increased, but only up to a maximum of 35 characters. (...)
>
> I increased the allowed length to 32 (...)
>
> *—[Shog9](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/13)*

Can we please increase our maximum tag length to **35 characters**, [so we can properly tag questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11017/19561) about the classic [do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep)?

#### Examples

Add examples of tags that would benefit from an increased maximum tag length below:

- *[Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11017/19561)* (35 characters)
- *[Guardians of the Galaxy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10980/19561)* (28 characters)
- ***The*** Curse of the Black Pearl (28 characters), although that's relatively minor
- [*Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9194/31394) (28 characters)
- *Jonathan Strange and Mr Norrell* (31 characters)
- *Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull* (32 characters)
  For the other films, removing "Indiana Jones and" is enough to pare it down to below 25 characters (although [raiders-of-the-lost-ark](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raiders-of-the-lost-ark) needed to lose "the" as well), but doing that here still leaves us with 28 (when removing "the") or 32 characters.

#### Process

I think it would be best *if* and *when* the tag length limit is increased, to open up a new question on meta, put specific cases as answers, and let the mods work their magic.

Comment: where was that 35 limit published, and what is the constraint? is there a MetaSE discussion somewhere which would be pertinent?

Comment: @can-ned_food I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: This likely won't happen soon, as Shog said in the linked post, their testing it on Lit, and we can probably expect that to take a couple of weeks if not a month.

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm patient.

Comment: @Edlothiad 6 to 8 weeks, to be precise.

Comment: @TimE.Lord looks like it took 8 weeks and a day. Guess they're failing their meme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The maximum tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/162011) for the entire Stack Exchange network on August 8, 2017.